# altair, set axis step to 1d

Tags: altair, vega-lite, vega

This is a simple altar viz:

```cs
alt.Chart(df).mark_area().encode(
    x="date:T",
    y="value:Q",
)
```

[image: viz]

I would like to have all days on X axis. On viz you can see `Sat 3`, `Wed 07` but I would like to have `Thu 01`, `Fri 02`, `Sat 03` and so on.

*( end of the question )*

---

I put here the whole minimal reproducible sample:

```cs
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# random data
l = [ 3,4,6,7,8,9,12,34,54,65,56,76,87,77,90 ] 
data ={
    'date': [ f'2022-09-{d:02d}' for d in range(1,31) ],
    'value': l + list(reversed(l)),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# viz
alt.Chart(df).mark_area().encode(
    x="date:T",
    y="value:Q",
)
```

Also, I write here that I have tried. I have tried unsuccessfully with several options like to include format, change angle or change size.

[image: viz with some axis options like format]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like the following:

[image]

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# random data
l = [ 3,4,6,7,8,9,12,34,54,65,56,76,87,77,90 ] 
data ={
    'date': [ f'2022-09-{d:02d}' for d in range(1,31) ],
    'value': l + list(reversed(l)),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# viz
alt.Chart(df).mark_area().encode(
    
    x=alt.X('date:O', axis=alt.Axis(format='' , labelExpr='date(datum.label) + " " + dayAbbrevFormat(day(datum.label))' ,title='date')),
    y="value:Q",
)
```